# Devexpress TreeList Child nodes

Tags: winforms, devexpress

How can i programmatically focus on child node in DevExpress TreeList?
Firstly i have to get selected node (parent or child) and then i have to focus on that node.
I tried using FocusedNode but i can only focus on parent node.

Example:

- 2013
- 2014

  - 3
  - 12 <- i want focus on this child node

What i'm getting using FocusedNode:

- 2013
- 2014 <- FocusedNode

  - 3
  - 12

Regards.

Comment: Show your code. How you're focusing the node? What is the condition that determines `12` should be the focused node?

Comment: Our project is developed with VB.
12 is an example: user selected 12, made some other action, and TreeList is refreshed. And 12 has to be still selected after refresh.

This is how i get node

previouslySelectedNode = DeclarationTreeList.FocusedNode

and focus on the node:
(separate method)
DeclarationTreeList.FocusedNode = previouslySelectedNode

Comment: [This](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E864) should help you

Comment: Thank you Sriram. Your example solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to find the child node and then just set it in the TreeList Focused node. Sample code in VB.Net is given below:

```
Dim NodeID As String = "some id" 'Set the child node id in this variable
Dim node = TreeList1.FindNodeByKeyID(NodeID)
TreeList1.FocusedNode = node
```